# How can we write a high performance and SAFE SQLCLR assembly to create and put a json object in MSMQ?

Tags: sql-server, json, msmq, sqlclr

There is a requirement in one of the projects i am working on, that, I need to create and pass some event messages in JSON format from SQL Server to MSMQ.

I found SQL CLR could be the best way to implement this. But, some my colleagues say that it is expensive in terms of performance and memory utilization.

I am looking for a benchmark of 20 msg/sec max.
No. of messages is depending upon certain events occured in the database.
The implementation is required to run for ~10hrs/day.

Kindly suggest on how to achieve it. Code snippet / steps will be a great help.

Any other option to implement the functionality is always welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 has native JSON capability, foregoing any need for an assembly. You're probably not using that, but I mention it in case you can upgrade, or are planning an upgrade in the near future.

Comment: 20 messages/sec is nothing. If you try hard enough you can probably write *interpreted T-SQL code* that can manage that (albeit code that would be horrible to write and maintain), let alone managed code. Unless your colleagues can provide evidence (as in, they've tried it themselves and ran into specific trouble, or can cite others who did) their advice should not be regarded more highly than something you benchmark yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> I found SQL CLR could be the best way to implement this. But, some my colleagues say that it is expensive in terms of performance and memory utilization.

There is a lot of "it depends" in this conversation. And, most of the performance / memory / security concerns you hear are based on misinformation or simple lack of information.

SQLCLR code *can* be inefficient, but it can also be more efficient / faster than T-SQL in some cases. It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish, *and* how you approach the problem, both in terms of overall structure as well as how it is coded. For things that can be done in straight T-SQL, then it is nearly always faster in straight T-SQL. But if you place that T-SQL code in a Scalar Function / UDF, then it is no longer fast ;-). Inline T-SQL is the fastest, IF you can actually do the thing you are trying to do.

So, if you can communicate with MSMQ via T-SQL, then do that. But if you can't, then yes, SQLCLR could be efficient enough to handle this.

HOWEVER #1, regarding the need for JSON:

I do not think that any of the [supported .NET Framework libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx) include JSON support (but I need to check again). While it is tempting to try to load Json.NET, certain coding practices are being done in that code that are not wise to use in SQLCLR, namely using static class variables. SQLCLR is a shared App Domain so all sessions running the same piece of code will share the same memory space. So the Json.NET code shouldn't be used as-is, it needs to be modified (if possible). Some people go the easy route and just set the Assembly to `UNSAFE` to get passed the errors about not being able to use static class variables that are not marked as `readonly`, but that can lead to odd / unexpected behavior so I wouldn't recommend it. There might also be references to unsupported .NET Framework libraries that would need to be loaded into SQL Server as `UNSAFE`. So, if you want to do JSON, you might have to [construct it manually](http://www.json.org/).

HOWEVER #2, the question title is (emphasis added):

> How can we write a high performance and ***SAFE*** SQLCLR assembly to create and put a json object in MSMQ?

you cannot interact with anything outside of SQL Server in an Assembly marked as `SAFE`. You will need to mark the Assembly as `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` in order to communicate with MSMQ, but that *shouldn't* pose any inherent problem.